Coefficients in each step of stepwise regression
I am using a stepwise regression in R, with this code:
model_scicareer_all <- glm(scicareer ~ .,
                           family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = clean_data)
summary(model_scicareer_all)

intercept_only <- glm(scicareer ~ -1,
                      family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = clean_data)

forward <- step(intercept_only, direction='forward', scope=formula(model_scicareer_all), trace=1000)

The code works without a problem. However, I would like to get the coefficients in each step. Is that possible? (I know that SPSS does this.)
I tried with different inputs, but I could not print the coefficients of each step

But that returns me only the coefficients of the final model, I want to get the coefficients of each step

But I do not want the coefficients of that model... I am looking for the coefficients of each model of each step in the stepwise regression

@stefan_aus_hannover coef is to return the coefficients of a model. step uses AIC to reduce/expand a model. in each step, only the AIC is reported and no model is returned. Then at the very end, the model is returned. So you can only access the coefficients of the final model and not of the intermediate models using coef

@stefan_aus_hannover use iris as the dataset

@Edward Its clearly possible. Check my solution below

step has the keep argument. Use this to obtain the coefficients of each model run:
example:
final <- step(lm(mpg~1,mtcars), DF2formula(mtcars),keep = \(x,y)list(coef(x)), trace = FALSE)
c(final$keep)
[[1]]
(Intercept) 
   20.09062 

[[2]]
(Intercept)          wt 
  37.285126   -5.344472 

[[3]]
(Intercept)          wt         cyl 
  39.686261   -3.190972   -1.507795 

[[4]]
(Intercept)          wt         cyl          hp 
 38.7517874  -3.1669731  -0.9416168  -0.0180381 


Note that you can keep anything. including the models themselves:
final <- step(lm(mpg~1,mtcars), DF2formula(mtcars),keep = \(x, y)list(x), trace = FALSE)

[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ 1, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
      20.09  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt  
     37.285       -5.344  


[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + cyl, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt          cyl  
     39.686       -3.191       -1.508  


[[4]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + cyl + hp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt          cyl           hp  
   38.75179     -3.16697     -0.94162     -0.01804  


better than my hacky version!

You can get the coefficients in a hacky way by capturing the output, extracting the formulas, and re-running the model for each formula. The last step below (dplyr::bind_rows()) is only necessary if you want to combine the coefficients in a table with NA values for coefficients not included in a particular model (this could certainly be done in  base R as well, but not as compactly).
fm <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
cc <- capture.output(step(fm))
## get all lines with a tilde but *without* a comma (the finally selected
##  model includes the formula, we don't want that line)
forms <- grep("~", cc, value = TRUE) |> 
         grep(pattern = ",", invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
## refit the model, get coefficients
coefs <- lapply(forms, \(f) coef(update(fm, formula = f)))
dplyr::bind_rows(coefs)

# A tibble: 8 × 11
  `(Intercept)`    cyl    disp      hp   drat    wt  qsec     vs    am   gear
          <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1         12.3  -0.111  0.0133 -0.0215  0.787 -3.72 0.821  0.318  2.52  0.655
2         11.0  NA      0.0128 -0.0219  0.835 -3.69 0.842  0.390  2.58  0.712
3          9.77 NA      0.0121 -0.0210  0.875 -3.71 0.911 NA      2.52  0.760
4          9.20 NA      0.0155 -0.0247  0.810 -4.13 1.01  NA      2.59  0.606
5         10.7  NA      0.0131 -0.0218  1.02  -4.04 0.991 NA      2.98 NA    
6         14.4  NA      0.0112 -0.0212 NA     -4.08 1.01  NA      3.47 NA    
7         17.4  NA     NA      -0.0176 NA     -3.24 0.811 NA      2.93 NA    
8          9.62 NA     NA      NA      NA     -3.92 1.23  NA      2.94 NA    
[...]


step has a trace argument but it seems it does not return coefficients. Instead use the trace function as shown.
trace(glm, exit = quote(print(coef(returnValue()))))
fm <- glm(mpg ~., data = mtcars)
step(fm)
untrace(flm)

